# Broadcast on contact add/change?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-contacts

Is there any standard broadcast intent that I can register a `BroadcastReceiver` for that gets triggered whenever a contact is added or changed? I've been looking through the docs for a while now but haven't found anything. Maybe it's hidden somewhere deep and one of you guys knows where.

Comment: check out my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29031605/1881527 it may help you...:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here I go answering my own question (if anyone has a better answer, don't be shy).

There's no broadcast when a contact is added/changed. However, when you look up your contacts in the [`RawContacts`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html) table you have a [`DIRTY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.SyncColumns.html#DIRTY) column which is `1` if the contact was changed since the last sync, which is pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: Are you sure that this is impossible? I wanted to be notified of a contact being added -- what are you doing? When are you checking to see if something is dirty?

Comment: Whenever the sync service is started. The OS *might* start your service automatically after adding a contact, but that's not guaranteed. I suppose you **could** register a content observer (see `ContentResolver.registerContentObserver`), but I think that would require you to have a `Service` running at all times when the device is awake (please stop it when the device goes to sleep).

Comment: @Felix I cannot understand one thing, suppose i update/delete a contact from the native app and the relevant flag gets set, now how can i be sure that when my sync adapter runs, the flags were not reset by the google sync adapter etc. ?
I know a bit about content providers and sync adapters but cannot figure this thing out. 
Please Help!