# Listen for changes to individual android contacts

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, contactscontract, contentobserver

I have a list of phone numbers and I need to be notified when changes occur to the contacts with those numbers in android contacts database.

***What I tried so far:***

**1st method:** Register a contentobserver:

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey), false,
mPresenceObserver);
```

, where mPresenceObserver is a ContentObserver. This way I get change notifications in the "onChange" method of the observer, but it happens when a change occurs to any contact in the database, not just the ones I am interested in. Also the URI that comes in the "onChange" looks like this: "content://com.android.contacts" (so it does not have appended any IDs that could help me identify which contact was changed).

**2nd method:** Query the database to retrieve the contacts I am interested in and set a ContentObserver on the Cursor. Unfortunately, the same thing happens as in previous method: I get notified when **ANY** change occurs to the database, instead of being notified when a change to the data that backs the cursor happens.

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733775/broadcast-on-contact-add-change