# Check contact list changed or not?

Tags: android, android-contacts, contact-list

I am developing an android application about contacts in phone, I want to do something when a new contact is added to contact. Is it possible to check either a contact is added to contact list?

Thanks.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5745955/1576416

Comment: use content observer