# Start Service when new contact is added

Tags: android

I am making a small whats app like  chat application . As i know whenever a new

contact is added to android device , what's app sends request to what's app server

for verifying that contact number is active on what's app or not , if it is active

it adds what's app icon to that contact. Same thing i want to apply for this .

whenever  a new contact is added to contact list , it must send request to

server .

So how can i do this in my app. how can i start new service whenever a new

contact is added .

Plz help . 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There's no broadcast when a contact is added/changed. However, when you look up your contacts in the [`RawContacts`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html) table you have a [`DIRTY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.SyncColumns.html#DIRTY) column which is `1` if the contact was changed since the last sync, which is pretty much what I was looking for.

Source: [Broadcast on contact add/change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733775/broadcast-on-contact-add-change)

In this way, when you know that a contact is dirty, you start a service (or make a broadcast that your receiver will receive).

Comment: Hi @Little Child , Thank you for your response . but can you plz tell me how can i get contact no. and contact name of updated contact using RawContacts ?