# How can I only query for the contacts that have been updated/edited? android

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

At the moment I have content observer set up which lets me know when any change happens to the contact. How can I only query for the contacts that have been updated such as the name field or phone number field in android using java?

```
class ContactObserver extends ContentObserver {
        public ContactObserver(Handler handler){
            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange){
            contactChanged();
        }
   }

public void contactChanged(){
       ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
       String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
                       ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
               };

       Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,PROJECTION,null,null,null);

       JSONArray contactsArray = new JSONArray();


       String name;
       String number;
       String id;

       try{
           if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
               do {

                   name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                   number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                   id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));

                   JSONObject contact = new JSONObject();
                   contact.put("id", id);
                   contact.put("name", name);
                   contact.put("number", number);

                   contactsArray.put(contact);

               }while(cursor.moveToNext());
           }
       }
       catch(JSONException ex){}

       //System.out.println(contactsArray.toString());
       getUpdatedContacts(contactsArray.toString(), pointer);

   }
```

Comment: have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5745955/5696047

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani can't really query for this flag..

Answer (score 0):

Use this code inside contactChanged(), and for more details on Contacts Provider [reference](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names)

```
// projection for the query
String[] projection = new String[]{
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP
};

// sort order for the query
String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP + " DESC";

// Query the Contacts Provider for recently updated contacts
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
        null,
        null,
        sortOrder
);

// Loop through the results and handle the recently updated contacts
if (cursor != null) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        Long lastUpdated = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP));
        // handle recently updated contacts here
    }
    cursor.close();
}

// Don't forget to unregister the ContentObserver.
```

Comment: Doesn't this just query the content provider for contacts on every change to the contacts and not just updated? I just want to get the updated contact and not all the contacts.

Comment: Why are you misusing the citation formatting in all your answers? Are you citing something, or is it your own text?